# the best way to calculate rms voltage from 10Hz to 20KHz

Tags: pic, adc, rms

We need to calculate the RMS voltage of a signal that can work from 10Hz to 20 KHz with a duty of 5% to 95%. I decided to use a dsPic33CK256EP202 with the ADC sampling at 500Ksps at 12 bits of resolution. But I have a problem with little ram memory to store the points of an entire cycle (when the signal frequency is less than 250Hz). I tried to dynamically calculate the rms sum during the interruption of each sample read, with the purpose of not having to save the samples in ram. However, in this way, the sampling speed drops to 60-70 Ksps. How would you go about computing this signal?

At the moment I am trying to use flash memory to make up for the lack of ram, however I am thinking that the flash recording time will be longer than the time interval between samples.

If someone has another reading topology, it is welcome.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve in terms of measurement precision and accuracy? Why are you sampling at 500Ksps, is that the free-running sampling conversion rate of the ADC? At 10Hz you are sampling at 50K times the signal frequency which is completely unnecessary. Is the signal a square wave?

Comment: Does your measurement have to produce ***two*** results: RMS voltage and also frequency? If so, think about both extremes of your 1:2000 dynamic range. How much repeatability do you expect for the RMS value and the frequency at 20 kHz? How will you achieve it? How many cycles are you allowed for the measurements at 20 kHz? Etc. We need much more detail than you are providing here.

Comment: Did you consider to use edge-triggered interrupts for the rising and falling edges of your signal? Combined with a timer captured by the edges you will get points in time to calculate all you need. Even with 20kHz you will have 50µs for each calculation, which should be more than enough. -- I'm not sure that your PIC can do this. You might need to select another micro.

Comment: Consider your duty cycle range from 5% to 95% and how to get enough samples during the 5% part of the waveform. A sample rate 20 times the waveform frequency would only get one sample during the 5% part. At least 3 samples are required, 5 would get the RMS voltage to about ±10%. That means minimum sample rate of 1.2M per second, with 2M getting acceptable accuracy.